# Xamarin - distribution certificate shows "Not in keychain"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Xamarin is telling me my distribution certificate is "not in my keychain".  Is this telling me the certificate isn't on my Mac keychain?  Or my Windows certificate store?  How do I make the status turn "Valid"?

Here is what I can see...

Under Tools/Options I click here...

[image]

And then it shows my Distribution certificate is "Not in keychain".

[image]

But on my Mac, the certificate is there.

[image]

How do I make it so Visual Studio sees the certificate as Valid?

Just for grins I downloaded and installed the same 2 certificates shown in the Mac keychain to my Windows certificate store, but the status remains "Not in keychain".  My understanding is the certificates need to be on the Mac and not on the Windows Xamarin machine, but now I am not so sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well they made it now by design that you have to import the certificate to Visual studio.

On your mac open the key vault, find your certificate, click on small dropdown arrow left of it to discover the private key, select both (!) certificate and private key lines then right-click and choose export. They will be saved to a p12 format (you would need to specify a simple password for it), then drop this file to your PC where (Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts) you will

[image: Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts]

import the certificate.
Then you would need to download all profiles for it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you point me to where this is documented?

Comment: The funny thing i didn't find it anywhere, "they" just implemented a feature in VS that broke stuff, on xamarin forums i was told to reinstall vs, recreate crtificates and more "delete bin obj suggestions", then after reading many complains on web i found a one-line post by a MS guy stating that it is not a bug but by design.